# Javascript calculator. Showing ' . ' and operation sign on screen

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

My calculator is almost done but for some reason, I can't get the '.' and operation sign to show on the screen. My numbers are working and the calculator is logging the operation sign and the dot but not displaying it. The dot is displayed once pressed and a number is added. And as I said they both appear in the console.

```
<div class="calc-grid">
    <div id="result">
        <div id="prev"></div>
        <div id="current"></div>
    </div>
    <button class='span' onClick="calculate(this)">AC</button>
    <button onClick="calculate(this)">DEL</button>
    <button onClick="calculate(this)">÷</button>
    <button onClick="calculate(this)">1</button>
    <button onClick="calculate(this)">2</button>
    <button onClick="calculate(this)">3</button>
    <button onClick="calculate(this)">*</button>
    <button onClick="calculate(this)">4</button>
    <button onClick="calculate(this)">5</button>
    <button onClick="calculate(this)">6</button>
    <button onClick="calculate(this)">+</button>
    <button onClick="calculate(this)">7</button>
    <button onClick="calculate(this)">8</button>
    <button onClick="calculate(this)">9</button>
    <button onClick="calculate(this)">-</button>
    <button onClick="calculate(this)">.</button>
    <button onClick="calculate(this)">0</button>
    <button class='span' onClick="calculate(this)">=</button>
</div>
```

```
current = 
prev = 
lastop = ''
tempcurrent = ''

function calculate(button) {
    let key = (button.textContent)
        if(key == 'AC'){
            current = 
            prev =
            lastop = ''
            tempcurrent = ''
        }
        if (key == 'DEL'){
            current = current.toString().slice(0, -1)
        }
        if ( key >= 0 || key == '.'){
            tempcurrent = tempcurrent + key
            current = parseFloat(tempcurrent)
        }
        if ( key == '+' || key == '-' || key == '÷' || key == '*' ) {
            lastop = key
            prev = current   
            current = ''
            tempcurrent = ''
        } 
        if ( key == '=' && lastop == '+'){
            current =  parseFloat(prev) + parseFloat(current) 
            prev = ''
        }
        if ( key == '=' && lastop == '-'){
            current = parseFloat(prev) - parseFloat(current) 
            prev = ''
        }
        if ( key == '=' &&  lastop == '*'){
            current = parseFloat(prev) * parseFloat(current) 
            prev = ''
        }
        if ( key == '=' && lastop == '÷'){
            current = parseFloat(prev) / parseFloat(current) 
            prev = ''
        }
    document.getElementById("current").innerHTML = current
    document.getElementById("prev").innerHTML = prev
    console.log(key)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `parseFloat()` removes it

for example if i run in console `parseFloat('1.')` it will return 1

Edit:

solution you can do:

```
      if (key >= 0) {
        tempcurrent = tempcurrent + key;
        current = parseFloat(tempcurrent);
      }
      if (key == ".") {
        tempcurrent = tempcurrent + key;
        current = tempcurrent;
      }
```

P.S. You can use switch for nicer code

Comment: ParseFloat() helps my calculations. is there anything else I can use?

Comment: see my edit, you can make a special case for it